# Create shortcut to dial VPN connection in Windows 8

Tags: vpn, windows-8

It was easy to create a shortcut that automatically dials a VPN connection in Windows 7 (e.g., see [these](https://superuser.com/a/186218/40666) [answers](https://superuser.com/a/240421/40666)). But if I create that shortcut in Windows 8, double-clicking it opens the Networks panel (and doesn't establish the connection).

How do I create a shortcut in Windows 8 that dials a VPN connection?

Comment: @Moab: That just creates a shortcut that opens the Networks panel to show the VPN connection (which I already know how to do). I want to create a shortcut that automatically connects, with no extra steps.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use the `rasphone` utility as documented in [KB555935](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555935). Assuming your VPN connection is named "Work VPN", follow these steps:

1. Right-click the desktop, choose **New > Shortcut**.
2. Enter `rasphone.exe` as the location of the item; click **Next**.
3. Type a name for the shortcut, e.g., "Work VPN"; click **Finish**.
4. Right-click the new shortcut, choose **Properties**.
5. Edit the **Target** to be `C:\Windows\System32\rasphone.exe -d "Work VPN"` (change the name to be the name of your VPN connection; to see the names of existing connections, just run `rasphone.exe` with no arguments).
6. (Optional) Click **Change Icon** and pick a better icon; there are a few icons of networks in Shell32.dll.

Comment: It's worth noting that `C:\Windows\System32\rasphone.exe -h "Work VPN"` can be used in a second shortcut for disconnecting the VPN connection (you can't use the -d shortcut, above, to toggle the state of the VPN connection, it can only be used to connect).

Comment: Thanks for this, but I feel the need to ask, with this setup, I know the password is saved, but it is still prompting for a user interaction to connect.  Is there a way to make it not ask that or am I missing something from this instruction?

Comment: My VPN credentials are saved and Windows provides them automatically without user intervention so it seems like there is something you are missing

Comment: Also if you want to have no prompt for Username and password make sure to "open %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk\rasphone.pbk in a text editor, make a backup of it
Find [YOURVPNNAME]
Find PreviewUserPw=1 - Change it to PreviewUserPw=0"

Answer (score 9):

I believe you were close..

The command you were looking for is `rasdial.exe`

Create the shortcut on your desktop as rasdial.exe then all you need to have is the name of the network. ie... `rasdial.exe "Work Network"` or whatever you have called your VPN Connection.

Then put it in your Startup folder just like you would any other program you want to run on startup.

1. Right-click the desktop, **choose New > Shortcut**.
2. Enter **rasdial.exe** as the location of the item; click Next.
3. Type a name for the shortcut, e.g., "Work VPN"; click Finish.
4. Right-click the new shortcut, choose **Properties**.
5. Edit the Target to be `C:\Windows\System32\rasdial.exe "Work
   Network"`

Copy the shortcut into your Startup folder: `%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\`

Answer (score -1):

You can also do the following steps to add a shortcut to the desktop:

- Step 1: Right click on Network icon (wireless or wired) on task bar
- Step 2: Left click on "Open Network and Sharing Center (menu item)"
- Step 3: Left click on "Change adapter settings (link)" in "Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Network and Sharing Center"
- Step 4: Right click on "Name (edit)" in "Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections"
- Step 5: Left click on "Create Shortcut (menu item)"
- Step 6: Left click on "Yes (button)" in "Shortcut"

Comment: This doesn't automatically dial the connection (as requested); it simply opens the Networks panel and I have to click the "Connect" button to establish the connection.