# Add a VPN shortcut to the desktop in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, vpn, shortcuts, desktop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create shortcut to dial VPN connection in Windows 8](https://superuser.com/questions/493749/create-shortcut-to-dial-vpn-connection-in-windows-8)

I'm new here, so if I misplaced this question please don't bite :)

I'm trying to add a shortcut to a VPN connection on my Windows 8 desktop. [This](https://superuser.com/questions/493749/create-shortcut-to-dial-vpn-connection-in-windows-8) thread deals with this specific question, however it doesn't solve it for me. I created the shortcut, but it just opens up the VPN connection dialog box.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When specifying `rasphone.exe -d "VPN Connection Name"`, did you specify the name properly, i.e. exactly as rasphone.exe with no arguments displays?

Comment: @Karan Yes. Exactly as stated.

Comment: Do you have the username/password saved in the connection? What about in the `rasdial` command?

Comment: @Luke The credentials are saved in the connection. I also tried rasdial, but it doesn't work, it just shows a Command Prompt window for a second, but doesn't switch on the connection. (P.S.: Does rasdial use the same syntax as rasphone?)

Comment: Try `rasdial connectionname Username password`