# How do you create a windows 8 tile to connect to a VPN?

Tags: networking, windows-8, vpn, connection, shortcuts

This is too deep in the charms since I use it constantly. I would like a tile that would either connect to the VPN or a tile that will open the network connections options within the charms menu.

I have the 8.1 preview installed so I can use Outlook to connect to my work Exchange account. This requires VPN, so this is why I will be connecting to the VPN constantly.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/493749/create-shortcut-to-dial-vpn-connection-in-windows-8

Comment: Just create a shortcut that works, then pin the short to the start menu, instant tile.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a way to automate it using the rasdial.exe command.

You can create a shortcut command or batch file with the following

rasdial.exe "VPN Name" username password

The batch file could be used as a script during startup.

A shortcut can be pinned to the start menu and taskbar.

If you are using 8.1 there is currently a bug that doesn't allow you to pin shortcuts from the desktop. So add it to the start menu folder (either in "Users" or "ProgramData") to get it into the All Apps section. The right click on it there to pin it to the start.